# Question mark near geometry in Ansys Mechanical

Tags: ansys

I am trying to do a linear buckling analysis for an omega stiffener.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zvpw.png)

I made the cad model using Autocad and exported to .iges format.

For simulations, I am using Ansys Mechanical and I seem to be getting a question mark near the geometry while importing. Moreover, there seems to be an "invalid assignment" error while clicking on solve.

Please help with any suggestions. I am new to this software. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't assign any material to your geometry.

The question mark means the software is missing required information (to solve) at this level. In this case it looks like the geometry is under-defined.